# Calculate a LookAt Matrix

Tags: java, opengl, matrix, jogl

I have been trying to write a view matrix/look at matrix but there is an error somewhere in my code and I need help finding it. When I use my function I get a blank screen rather than the test view of my triangle that I should be getting.

```
public static Mat4 lookAt(
float eyeX, float eyeY, float eyeZ,     //Where we are looking from
float centreX, float centreY, float centreZ, //Where we are looking to
float upX, float upY, float upZ)        //Which way is up
{
    Vec3 eye    = new Vec3(eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ);
    Vec3 target = new Vec3(centreX, centreY, centreZ);
    Vec3 up     = new Vec3(upX, upY, upZ);

    Vec3 zaxis = normal(subtract(target,eye)); // The "forward" vector.
    Vec3 xaxis = normal(cross(up, zaxis));     // The "right" vector.
    Vec3 yaxis = cross(zaxis, xaxis);          // The "up" vector.


    // [ right.x    right.y     right.z  0]
    // [   up.x       up.y       up.z    0]
    // [-forward.x -forward.y -forward.z 0]
    // [    0         0           0      1]

    Mat4 orientation = new Mat4(
       new Vec4( xaxis.get()[0], yaxis.get()[0], -zaxis.get()[0], +0.0f ),  //Column 1 
       new Vec4( xaxis.get()[1], yaxis.get()[1], -zaxis.get()[1], +0.0f ),  //Column 2 
       new Vec4( xaxis.get()[2], yaxis.get()[2], -zaxis.get()[2], +0.0f ),  //Column 3 
       new Vec4( +0.0f, +0.0f,  +0.0f,  +1.0f)                  //Column 4 
       ); 

Mat4 translation = new Mat4 (
        new Vec4( +1.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f ), //Column 1
        new Vec4( +0.0f, +1.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f ), //Column 2
        new Vec4( +0.0f, +0.0f, +1.0f, +0.0f ), //Column 3
        new Vec4( -eye.get()[0], -eye.get()[1], -eye.get()[2], +1.0f)   //Column 4
        );      

    return multiply(orientation, translation);
}
```

This is for a right handed coordinate system. All the matrices are column major; they are constructed starting at a11, moving down the first column to a41, then to a12 and so on to a44.

I have gone over the following functions and I am fairly sure they are correct but I have included them just in case I have overlooked something:

```
Vec3 normal(Vec3 a)
{
    Vec3 unit;

    float[] v_a = a.get();
    float   v_mag = magnitude(a);

    unit = new Vec3(v_a[0]/v_mag, v_a[1]/v_mag, v_a[2]/v_mag);

    return unit;
}
```

--

```
float magnitude(Vec3 a)
{
    float[] v_a = a.get();


    return( (float)Math.sqrt(
    Math.pow( (double)v_a[0], 2) +
    Math.pow( (double)v_a[1], 2) +
    Math.pow( (double)v_a[2], 2)
    )   // -- end sqrt --
); // -- return --
}
```

--

```
Vec3 cross(Vec3 a, Vec3 b)
{
    Vec3 crossProduct;

    float[] v_a = a.get();
    float[] v_b = b.get();

    crossProduct = new Vec3(
       v_a[1]*v_b[2] - v_a[2]*v_b[1],   //cx = ay*bz - az*by
       v_a[2]*v_b[0] - v_a[0]*v_b[2],   //cy = az*bx - ax*bz
       v_a[0]*v_b[1] - v_a[1]*v_b[0]    //cz = ax*by - ay*bz
   ); 

return(crossProduct);
}
```

All the vector assignments are correct. get() returns a float[].

Comment: Maybe you should look at the source code of javax.media.opengl.glu.GLU.gluLookAt().

Comment: I have looked at the source code, the problem I am having is that there is an error in my code and I need help finding that - I can't do that by looking over the GLU source code again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using an algorithm similar to the one described on this page:
http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~gfx/Courses/1999/intro.fall99.html/lookat.html.

It appears that you are negating the wrong thing in your orientation matrix. You negate the z component of each of your axis vectors when really you should negate the entire zaxis vector in the orientation matrix.

Comment: Yes, you are right that was an error. However there must be another one somewhere as changing this still didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Could you post the code of how you are using the lookat matrix and where you are drawing the triangle?